# How to add scheme and path to url.URL

Tags: url, go

I'm trying to update a parsed URL the following way:

```
u, _ := url.Parse(s)
if u.Scheme == "" {
    u.Scheme = "https"
}
if u.Path == "" {
    u.Path = "api"
}
```

But it turns out that if the initial string lacks the URL scheme (e.g. `example.com`) that string is parsed as `URL.Path` and not `URL.Host`. See this [Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/mbNK3x_uqQ).

How can I turn this `example.com` into this `https://example.com/api`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a check:

```
if !strings.HasPrefix(s, "http://") && !strings.HasPrefix(s, "https://") {
        s = "https://" + s
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dDK0nx-8x-

Answer (score 1):

The Parse function works off of [RFC 3986 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) which requires the authority (host and port) to be preceeded by `//`.

> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
> hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
> / path-absolute
> / path-rootless
> / path-empty

According to this spec the leading `//` is required and the Parse function enforces that. The string you pass to the Parse function can include a blank URL scheme, but it does have to include a `//` before the hostname and port for it to parse those parts correctly. How you want to enforce having that leading `//` is up to you.